# the description of onDidLoadFromCCB(cocos2d-x js binding)

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

When I review the codes of js sample I saw

```
MenuLayerController.prototype.onDidLoadFromCCB
```

I check online help

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/html5-js/index.html

but can not find the description of onDidLoadFromCCB

Is there anyone know if onDidLoadFromCCB is the fixed function of cc or not?

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `onDidLoadFromCCB` method is part of CCB Reader: it is called once the scene has been created from the corresponding CCB file.

Corresponding source code is here: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/master/scripting/javascript/bindings/js/jsb_cocosbuilder.js#L105

I'm not sure there is any documentation for that.